# Uniqueness of localic analogue of Radon-Nikodym derivatives

Tags: pr.probability, constructive-mathematics, locales

In classical probability theory, Radon-Nikodym derivatives are unique up to measure-0 sets of the background measure. I am wondering whether the following statement, intended to state an analogue of this fact for valuations on locales, holds:

> Suppose we have a probability distribution $\mu$ over a locale $A$
>   such that, for any opens $U$ and $V$ of $A$, if $\mu(U) = \mu(U \wedge V)$,
>   then $U \le V$ (when this condition holds, we call $A$ a *random locale* with respect to $\mu$, as in [Simpson's *Measure, Randomness and Sublocales* (2011)](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/als/Research/Sources/mrs.pdf)). Further
>   suppose we have "Radon-Nikodym derivatives" $f, g : A \to R$ (where
>   $R$ is the locale of non-negative lower reals, including $\infty$) whose integrals against
>   $\mu$ define probability distributions $\nu_f$ and $\nu_g$ over $A$,
>   respectively. Then if $\nu_f$ and $\nu_g$ are identical, so are $f$ and $g$.

---

#### My progress so far

I believe that I have proved that it holds (allowing nonconstructive reasoning) if either of the following conditions hold in addition:

- Either $f$ or $g$ is bounded.
- The locale $A$ admits a finite base.

I'll briefly explain why I believe it holds with either of the above additional conditions. I believe I have a proof of the following lemma:

> Given a finite (but nonzero) valuation $\mu$ over $A$ such that $A$ is a random locale w.r.t. $\mu$, and given $f, g : A \to R$ such that $f < g$, meaning that $f \le g$ (in terms of specialization order) and also there is some $U$ such that $f^*(U) < g^*(U)$ (where $f^*$ is the inverse image map for $f$ and likewise for $g^*$, and where strict inequality $<$ on opens of locales is defined so that $U < V$ means $U \le V$ and $\neg (V \le U)$), then as long as $\int_A f d\mu < \infty$,
>   $$ \int_A f d\mu < \int_A g d\mu.$$

Using this lemma, we can then make the following argument:

(Allowing nonconstructive reasoning,) We instead prove that if $f$ is different from $g$, then $\nu_f$ is different from $\nu_g$.

Suppose there were a $q : \mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $f^*(\cdot > q) < g^*(\cdot > q)$ and such that for all $q' : \mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $q \le q'$, we have $f^*(\cdot > q') \le g^*(\cdot > q')$. Then we would have 
$f|_{g^*(\cdot > q)} < g|_{g^*(\cdot > q)}$, and by the previous lemma, we would derive
$$\int_{g^*(\cdot > q)} f d\mu < \int_{g^*(\cdot > q)} g d\mu,$$
which would contradict what we are told, that $\nu_f = \nu_g$.

We know since $f \ne g$ that there is some $q$ such that (w.l.o.g.) $f^*(\cdot > q) < g^*(\cdot > q)$, so that mean there must be some $q' : \mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $q < q'$ and $f^*(\cdot > q') > g^*(\cdot > q')$. Thus we can keep repeating this process, giving us an infinite sequence $(q_n)_{n : \mathbb{N}}$ of positive rationals where the containment of level sets keeps swapping, that is, alternating between $f$ being bigger than $g$ and vice versa. The sequence $q_n$ must not be bounded, because otherwise, by continuity it could not be the case that $f$ and $g$ keep swapping. So $q_n$ must be unbounded. The sequence of opens $f^*(\cdot > q_n)$ must also decrease towards $\bot$ as $n$ increases. If instead there were a positive open $U$ such that for all $n$, $U \le f^*(\cdot > q_n)$, then we would find that $\int_U f d\mu$ was $\infty$ (since the sequence $q_n$ is unbounded).

If $f$ is bounded, it would contradict the fact that $q_n$ is unbounded and $f^*(\cdot > q_n)$ is always positive. If $A$ admits a finite base, then there cannot be an infinite decreasing chain of positive opens of $A$ given by $f^*(\cdot > q_n)$.

In light of this, if one were searching for counterexamples to the statement without the additional conditions, it might make sense to consider $A = R$, where $f, g : R \to R$ increase as their arguments tend to $\infty$, in such a way that their graphs cross infinitely many times.

---

#### References

[Alex Simpson. *Measure, Randomness and Sublocales*. 2011.](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/als/Research/Sources/mrs.pdf)
This paper defines "random" locales.

[Steve Vickers. *A monad of valuation locales*. 2011.](http://www.computer-science.birmingham.ac.uk/~sjv/Riesz.pdf)
This paper describes an analogue of the Riesz representation theorem, giving a correspondence between valuations and lower-real valued linear functionals over lower-real valued continuous maps.

Comment: Quick comment: You have not defined < on A. Also, in your conclusion, $R$ is not a random locale, as you seem to assume in the beginning of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful remarks! I intended that for any locale $A$ and opens $U, V$ of $A$, $U < V$ means $U \le V$ and $\neg (V \le U)$. Perhaps there is a negation-less way to phrase everything. I think the probability distribution $\mu$ on $R$ given by $\mu(\cdot > q) = 1 - \frac{1}{2 + q}$ is such that $R$ is random w.r.t. $\mu$.

Comment: Oops, I meant $\mu(\cdot > q) = \frac{1}{2+q}$.

Comment: Are you thinking of Ran(R) the smallest sublocale of the same measure?(Simpson's Thm 2). Has this theorem been generalized to infinite measures? (It's been a while since I looked at the paper.)

Comment: I am primarily thinking of $\mathsf{Ran}(\mu)$ as the sublocale given by the quotient $U \equiv V$ whenever $\mu(U) = \mu(U \wedge V) = \mu(V)$, and secondarily as the smallest sublocale of the same measure, though Simpson's characterization with Thm 2 does require that the locale be fitted. I doubt that the theorem generalizes to infinite measures (if I have discussed infinite measures then I didn't notice it and it is an accident).